# How do you add pageup/pagedown keybindings to TextArea in python-prompt-toolkit?

Tags: python, textarea, prompt-toolkit

Let's use [calculator.py](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit/blob/22a397a75058d45d8a56857ce2d753c00b0e5f15/examples/full-screen/calculator.py) for example.

To add a scrollbar that works with the mouse wheel, you would change:

```py
output_field = TextArea(style="class:output-field", text=help_text)
```

[image: calculator.py without scrollbar]

to:

```py
output_field = TextArea(style="class:output-field", text=help_text, scrollbar=True)
```

[image: calculator.py with scrollbar]

But what would you add or change to scroll the `TextArea` with the page up and page down keys?

```py
# The key bindings.
kb = KeyBindings()

@kb.add("pageup")
def _(event):
    # What goes here?
    pass

@kb.add("pagedown")
def _(event):
    # What goes here?
    pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Change focus

The simplest way would probably be to import `focus_next` (or `focus_previous`)

```
from prompt_toolkit.key_binding.bindings.focus import focus_next
```

and bind it to Control-Space (or anything else).

```
# The key bindings.
kb = KeyBindings()

kb.add("c-space")(focus_next)
```

### Keep focus

You could also, to seemingly keep the focus on `input_field`, import `scroll_page_up` and `scroll_page_down`

```
from prompt_toolkit.key_binding.bindings.page_navigation import scroll_page_up, scroll_page_down
```

then switch focus to `output_field`, call `scroll_page_up`/`scroll_page_down` and finally change focus back to `input_field`.

```
# The key bindings.
kb = KeyBindings()

@kb.add("pageup")
def _(event):
    w = event.app.layout.current_window
    event.app.layout.focus(output_field.window)
    scroll_page_up(event)
    event.app.layout.focus(w)

@kb.add("pagedown")
def _(event):
    w = event.app.layout.current_window
    event.app.layout.focus(output_field.window)
    scroll_page_down(event)
    event.app.layout.focus(w)
```

Comment: The second one worked perfectly for my use case, thank you! In my case, I need to always keep focus on the input field while having the option to scroll the output field. The input field acts as the command prompt and the output field acts as the command output/history.